# Wifi no available

Tags: iwlwifi

I have installed Lubuntu 20.04 along side windows 11 on Satellite M-305-4910 and I cannot have wifi working even though it works with windows.Can you please provide some help on this matter?
kindly see some information for guidance:

description: Notebook
product: Satellite M305
vendor: TOSHIBA
version: PSMD8U-023013
serial: 39052110W
width: 64 bits

sudo iwconfig

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp7s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp8s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
```

aaa@aaa-satellitem305:~$ rfkill list

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
```

thank you so much for the assistacne

Comment: *Hard Blocked: yes* typically means that the wireless is disabled by the switch or key combination, sometimes called Airplane Mode. Perhaps Fn+F8.  Please check. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)